# How download files in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to implement file download in my MVC project. I have a repository there I upload file but this repository not is in my Project folder i.e. it is e: drive while my running project in is c: drive.

I get the file url info like below "http://cdn1.zerofootprint.com.au/ASSETS/4785/Photography/mstestDesert.jpg" 
and I a'm binding these url dynamically.

Is there ant way to download these file with the help of anchor. 
Any sample code will be much appreciated.

```html
<div class="image">
<a href="http://cdn1.zerofootprint.com.au/ASSETS/4785/Photography/mstestDesert.jpg" >
  <img src="http://cdn1.zerofootprint.com.au/ASSETS/4785/Photography/mstestDesert.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="mstestDesert.jpg">
</a>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'download' attribute

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seano666/5k4fcjbe/)

```
<div class="image">
<a href="http://cdn1.zerofootprint.com.au/ASSETS/4785/Photography/mstestDesert.jpg" download>
  <img src="http://cdn1.zerofootprint.com.au/ASSETS/4785/Photography/mstestDesert.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="mstestDesert.jpg">
</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: it is not supported in IE and Safari

Comment: True, but there are some cross browser solutions out there also.  http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/